# How to swap the even and odd lines via bash script?

Tags: string, bash

In the incoming string stream from the standard input, swap the even and odd lines.
I've tried to do it like this, but reading from file and `$i -lt $a.count` aren't working:

```
$a= gc test.txt
for($i=0;$i -lt $a.count;$i++)
{
if($i%2)
{
$a[$i-1]
}
else
{
$a[$i+1]
}
}
```

Please, help me to get this working

Comment: You should ask this on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), because likely there is another program that can help (e.g. `sed`). That means this is maybe not a programming question.

Comment: what language/shell is the given code written in? (it's definitely not `bash`); consider updating the question with a) sample input data, b) the (wrong) output generated by your code and c) the (correct) expected output

Comment: See: [Swap every 2 lines in a file](https://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/swap-every-2-lines-in-file.html)

Comment: The `sed` and `awk` solutions in [Swap every 2 lines in a file](https://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/swap-every-2-lines-in-file.html) look OK to me (though I haven't tested them thoroughly).  However, the shell code is completely incompetent.  The best that can be said about it is that it works on the author's test file.  It will break on many many input files though.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting one line `awk` script:

```
awk '!(NR%2){print$0;print r}NR%2{r=$0}' input.txt
```

#### `awk` script explanation

```
!(NR % 2){ # if row number divide by 2 witout reminder
  print $0; # print current row
  print evenRow; # print saved row
}
(NR % 2){ # if row number divided by 2 with reminder
  evenRow = $0; # save current row in variable
}
```

Comment: This works well on everything that I've thrown at it except that it silently discards the final line if the input has an odd number of lines.  It's not clear if that is what @Oleg wanted, but I think it's at least worth documenting the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a good `awk`-based answer to the question here, and there are a few decent-looking `sed` and `awk` solutions in [Swap every 2 lines in a file](https://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/swap-every-2-lines-in-file.html).  However, the shell solution in [Swap every 2 lines in a file](https://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/swap-every-2-lines-in-file.html) is almost comically incompetent.  The code below is an attempt at a functionally correct pure Bash solution.  Bash is very slow, so it is practical to use only on small files (maybe up to 10 thousand lines).

```
#! /bin/bash -p

idx=0 lines=()
while IFS= read -r 'lines[idx]' || [[ -n ${lines[idx]} ]]; do
    (( idx == 1 )) && printf '%s\n%s\n' "${lines[1]}" "${lines[0]}"
    idx=$(( (idx+1)%2 ))
done
(( idx == 1 )) && printf '%s\n' "${lines[0]}"
```

- The `lines` array is used to hold two consecutive lines.
- `IFS=` prevents whitespace being stripped as lines are read.
- The `idx` variable cycles through `0, 1, 0, 1, ...` (`idx=$(( (idx+1)%2 ))`) so reading to `lines[idx]` cycles through putting input lines at indexes `0` and `1` in the `lines` array.
- The `read` function returns non-zero status immediately if it encounters an unterminated final line in the input.  That could cause the loop to terminate before processing the last line, thus losing it in the output.  The `|| [[ -n ${lines[idx]} ]]` avoids that by checking if the `read` actually read some input.  (Fortunately, there's no such thing as an unterminated empty line at the end of a file.)
- `printf` is used instead of `echo` to output the lines because `echo` doesn't work reliably for arbitrary strings.  (For instance, a line containing just `-n` would get lost completely by `echo "$line"`.)  See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).
- The question doesn't say what to do if the input has an odd number of lines.  This code (`(( idx == 1 )) && printf '%s\n' "${lines[0]}"`) just passes the last line through, after the swapped lines.  Other reasonable options would be to drop the last line or print it preceded by an extra blank line.  The code can easily be modified to do one of those if desired.
- The code is [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean.